# function strtol in C out of range... or not

Tags: c, std, strtol

I try to read a number from a string with strtol() and it returns the LONG_MAX number which is supposed to return when the number is out of range, but my number is not that big

```
main(){
    char linea[30]={"110111010111111000000000"};
    long num=strtol(linea,NULL,0);
    printf("%s\n%X",linea,num);
}
```

Actual Result:
110111010111111000000000
7FFFFFFF

Needed Result:
110111010111111000000000
DD7C00

Comment: @pyCthon - it's good practice not to include boilerplate when posting to SO.  you should #include <stdio.h> and #include <stdlib.h>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the man page for strtol, the '0' argument you've given means 'use you best judgement', which in this case is *decimal*.  If you want it to convert a *binary* number, as the 'Needed result' you've specified suggests, don't use '0', use '2'.

Answer (score 0):

probably because you pass in base 0

try:

```
int main(){
    char linea[30] = {"110111010111111000000000"};
    long num       = strtol(linea, NULL, 10);
    printf("%s\n%X", linea, num);
}
```

**EDIT**
Apparently base 0 is a special value for the `strtol` function:

> If the value of base is 0, the expected form of the subject sequence
>   is that of a decimal constant, octal constant, or hexadecimal
>   constant, any of which may be preceded by a '+' or '-' sign.

So I guess you can use 0, sorry for doubting you.

Comment: @Als hmm well apparently 0 is a special value, which I didnt know until you questioned me. Thanks, ill edit above.

Comment: Based on the expected output, it appears that he wants the input to be interpreted as base 2.

Comment: Yeah the base was actually 2 but that was the problem I don't know how I didn't see

Comment: Please edit your answer to add the solution to OP's problem which you soon realized & I will upvote your answer to negate out someones hasty downvote to your answer.